# Fail to wake up from epoll_wait when other process closes fifo

Tags: linux, select, multiprocessing, fifo, epoll

I'm seeing different `epoll` and `select` behavior in two different binaries and was hoping for some debugging help. In the following, `epoll_wait` and `select` will be used interchangeably.

I have two processes, one writer and one reader, that communicate over a fifo. The reader performs an `epoll_wait` to be notified of writes. I would also like to know when the writer closes the fifo, and it appears that `epoll_wait` should notify me of this as well. The following toy program, which behaves as expected, illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  const char* filename = "tempfile";
  char buf[1024];
  memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

  struct stat statbuf;
  if (!stat(filename, &statbuf))
    unlink(filename);

  mkfifo(filename, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (!pid) {
    int fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY);
    printf("Opened %d for writing\n", fd);
    sleep(3);
    close(fd);
  } else {
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    printf("Opened %d for reading\n", fd);

    static const int MAX_LENGTH = 1;
    struct epoll_event init;
    struct epoll_event evs[MAX_LENGTH];
    int efd = epoll_create(MAX_LENGTH);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; ++i) {
        init.data.u64 = 0;
        init.data.fd = fd;
        init.events |= EPOLLIN | EPOLLPRI | EPOLLHUP;
        epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &init);
    }

    while (1) {
      int nfds = epoll_wait(efd, evs, MAX_LENGTH, -1);
      printf("%d fds ready\n", nfds);
      int nread = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
      if (nread < 0) {
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
      } else if (!nread) {
        printf("Child %d closed the pipe\n", pid);
        break;
      }
      printf("Reading: %s\n", buf);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However, when I do this with another reader (whose code I'm not privileged to post, but which makes the exact same calls--the toy program is modeled on it), the process does not wake when the writer closes the fifo. The toy reader also gives the desired semantics with `select`. The real reader configured to use `select` also fails.

What might account for the different behavior of the two? For any provided hypotheses, how can I verify them? I'm running Linux 2.6.38.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) is a great tool to confirm that the system calls are invoked correctly (i.e. parameters are passed correctly and they don't return any unexpected errors).

In addition to that I would recommend using [lsof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) to check that no other process has that FIFO still opened.

Comment: Apologies for the (extremely) late response. The fifo was indeed open, and lsof helped me see it.